# Java - How to properly circumvent Illegal access exception in this case

Tags: java, reflection

I'm having this weird issue where even though (I think) I'm setting everything to be accessible correctly, I'm still getting IllegalAccessException.

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class
>   com.sasha.eventsys.SimpleEventManager can not access a member of class
>   com.sasha.proxy.discord.DiscordMain with modifiers "private"

```
public void invokeEvent(SimpleEvent e){
    registeredMethods.forEach(method -> {
        if (method.getParameterTypes()[0] == e.getClass()){
            try {
                Class clasz = method.getDeclaringClass();
                for (Field field : clasz.getFields()) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                }
                for (Method meth : clasz.getMethods()) {
                    meth.setAccessible(true);
                }
                for (Constructor<?> constructor : clasz.getConstructors()) {
                    constructor.setAccessible(true);
                }
                method.setAccessible(true);
                method.invoke(clasz.newInstance(), e);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                System.out.println("FATAL EXCEPTION DURING " + e.getClass().getName() + "'s EXECUTION");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the code that's invoking the method. In theory those for loops should be setting everything to be accessible, r-right?

````
@SimpleEventHandler
public void onMcMsgRecieved(MinecraftMessageRecievedEvent e){
    if(Config.doDiscord) {
        DiscordMain.theChannel = DiscordMain.findTheServer(jda.getTextChannelsByName(Config.channelName,false));
        if (Config.aestheticDiscord) {
            DiscordMain.renderViewport(e.getPlainText(), DiscordMain.theChannel, Caches.messagesRecieved==0);
            Caches.messagesRecieved++;
        }
        else {
            DiscordMain.theChannel.sendMessage("```html\n" + e.getPlainText().replace("discord.gg", "zozzle.gg").replace("`", "'").replaceAll("\247[^z]", "") + "\n```").submit();
        }
        Webhooks.pushToHook("```html\n" + e.getPlainText().replace("discord.gg", "zozzle.gg").replace("`", "'").replaceAll("\247[^z]", "") + "\n```");
    }
}
````

And here's where it's supposedly not able to access something. For reference all of the fields and methods called in this block are public or public static, so like, I don't get why it's having problems.

Comment: Can you post whole error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflection instances of `Field`, methods, constructors etc are only a copy and `.setAccessible` only affects that copy, so code like

```
            for (Field field : clasz.getFields()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }
```

does nothing.

In your case I would guess that `.newInstance` is throwing that error as no-args constructor is private? If that is true then you need to fetch constructor manually via `.getDeclaredConstructor()` method and set it to accessible and use it to create new instance.

Comment: True, but OP sets accessible true before the invocation, so your answer doesn't explain the exception

Comment: @Bohemian OP also didn't explain where he got that error. but see my edit, maybe it is about .newInstance

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so it seems that most likely, your answer is correct.

Comment: Then accept it too, about issue, isn't it that this field you want to change is static too? As I see many static usages in your code, then just pass null: `field.set(null, newValue)` (but such amount of static code looks pretty bad)